# Vba coding Excel to powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

High level issues : I want to send specific data from a userform into a row  within one sheet in excel. Then I want to send that row into a powerpoint file.

I have a userform which will correctly send data into excel rows.

I have formatted the powerpoint presentation but I have no ideas what the format is called in vba terms.

Each row of data will need to create a new slide with the same formating each time.

The userform will need to send  2 pictures into shapes in powerpoint. And about 7 cells of "string"  data for each row.

Comment: Show us what you tried so far so it will be more clear what's left to do.

Comment: If it's a picture you want to move across, then you can use `Range.CopyPicture` in Excel, and `Slide.Shapes.Paste` in PowerPoint to paste a Bitmap Image of the Excel range.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked two questions:

1. How to transfer data from a userform to a sheet,
2. How to transfer data from a sheet to Powerpoint.

I've answered the second question.

---

- In `Powerpoint` add a table to a slide.

  - Select the table and click `Selection Pane` in the `Layout` ribbon.
    This will bring up the `Selection and Visibility` Window.
    From here you can rename the table which will initially be named as `Content Placehold x`

    - I inserted the table on `Slide 2` and named it `MyTable`.
  - Save the presentation and close `Powerpoint`.
- Create a new workbook in `Excel`.

  - Add data to a row.
    I inserted values in the range `A2:E2` to match the five columns in the `Powerpoint` table I created.
  - Add a new code module to the `Excel` file.
  - This code will create an instance of `Powerpoint` from within `Excel`:

---

```
Private Function CreatePPT(Optional bVisible As Boolean = True) As Object

    Dim oTmpPPT As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set oTmpPPT = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER
        Set oTmpPPT = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
    End If

    oTmpPPT.Visible = bVisible
    Set CreatePPT = oTmpPPT

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure CreatePPT."
            Err.Clear
    End Select

End Function
```

---

- This code will set a reference to `Powerpoint` (opening it if necessary), open the presentation and transfer the data from `Sheet1!A2:E2` into table in `Powerpoint`:

---

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim oPPT As Object
    Dim oPresentation As Object
    Dim oSlide As Object
    Dim x As Long
    Dim rCell As Object

    Set oPPT = CreatePPT 'Get instance of PPT.

    'Powerpoint is in same folder as Excel -
    Set oPresentation = oPPT.Presentations.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\My PPTX.pptx")
    Set oSlide = oPresentation.Slides(2)

    With oSlide
        'Add text to the title shape.
        .Shapes("Title 1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "My Example Table"

        'Populate each cell in row 2 of the table.
        For Each rCell In .Shapes("MyTable").Table.Rows(2).Cells
            x = x + 1
            rCell.Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, x)
        Next rCell
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I have a functioning user form that is placing data into columns correctly, but this is the limit to my understanding. i had to borrow alot of code to get here.what I'm needing the code to do is: take this data from my user form and place it into text boxes on a power point slide. each time i enter a submission i need a new line to be created in the same power point sheet. I do not know how to submit pictures on here to show